# iOS App terminates in connectionDidFinishLoading

Tags: ios

iOS app terminates in Xcode simulator in connectionDidFinishLoading on the following line of code.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil];
```

Following the more code of this function

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection {
NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(URLConnection*)connection];
NSInteger statusCode=[((URLConnection*)connection).response statusCode];
NSString *tag=((URLConnection*)connection).tagKey;

[self removeReceivedDataHandle:tag];

if (statusCode != 200 && statusCode!=204 && statusCode!=405){
    [reportActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [transactionsActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [swipeHQCheckout showMessage:PHRASE_ServerCommunicationError];
    return;
}

if ([reports count] == 0) {
    [self removeReceivedDataHandle];
    [transactionsActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
    return;
}

SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
[reports removeObject:tag];

if ([tag isEqualToString:API_TransactionReport] ||
    [tag isEqualToString:API_FetchTransactions]) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil]; // here issue

    NSString *response_code=[dict objectForKey:@"response_code"]; 
// more code down here
}
```

What could be the issue, advanced thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Can you post the error/crash message?

Comment: Sorry @ParasGorasiya as I am very new in this, can you please suggest how to check crash message? There is nothing in the console regarding this.

Comment: If your app is crashing/terminating you should see a reason for crash on console otherwise its hard to answer or you may wish to post more code to have some detailed idea regarding the issue.

Comment: @ParasGorasiya I have added the function code block as well i nthe question details. Please have a look.

Comment: Hello, can you put try catch to this line of code and print the error in the catch?

Comment: Check if your dataForConnection method returns any data and also check whether you are receiving any data from API.

Comment: @ArpitJain yes it seems that it is the reason, I tried to show it in NSLog and there is EXC_BAD_ACCESS on this line now.

Comment: Okay check my answer , accept if it worked

Answer (score 0):

It seems your NSMutableData `dataForConnection` is coming nil and you are initializing a NSMutableDictionary with nil value

To avoid crash :

```
if (dataForConnection != nil){
     NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil]; 
}else{
    NSLog(@"NO Data");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did this before the line with error but it is still there. Following is code

`if (dataForConnection == nil){
            NSLog(@"No Data");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Data");
            NSLog(@"%@",dataForConnection);
        }
        
        
        
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil]; // error here `

It displayed Data and then EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line after else block.

Comment: It shows the error on 'NSLog(@"%@",dataForConnection);' line. EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Why are you putting      NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil];  after else bracket. It has to be inside else

Answer (score 0):

You should add the check at the start of the method to follow best practise, like

```
if (dataForConnection == nil){
      NSLog(@"NO Data");
      return;
}else{
    //Do whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did this before the line with error but it is still there. Following is code

`if (dataForConnection == nil){
            NSLog(@"No Data");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Data");
            NSLog(@"%@",dataForConnection);
        }
        
        
        
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [parser objectWithString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataForConnection encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] error:nil]; // error here `

It displayed Data and then EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the line after else block.

Comment: It shows the error on 'NSLog(@"%@",dataForConnection);' line. EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Have you added the code shown in answer after first line in connectionDidFinishLoading method? And you should also add return; call inside if block.

Comment: Now I did like that, there is data as shown below but after showing data, error on the I mentioned before.

`2017-08-01 12:48:33.048 SwipeHQC[79505:3807288] Data
2017-08-01 12:48:33.048 SwipeHQC[79505:3807288] <7b227265 73706f6e 73655f63 6f646522 3a323030 2c226d65 73736167 65223a22 4f4b222c 22646174 61223a7b 22737461 72744461 7465223a 22323031 372d3038 2d303122 2c22656e 64446174 65223a22 32303137 2d30382d 3031222c 22746f74 `

In the connectionDidFinishLoading method first line is 

`NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(URLConnection*)connection];`